# Use data from two separate JSON files in one function

Tags: javascript, json

I have two local JSON files that I'm trying to access in a function in my main.js file.  Everything works fine with just one JSON file, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the second.  Ideally, something like `data_set1=$.getJSON("file1.json")` would work perfectly, but I see similar questions have been repeatedly asked and because of asynchronous calls, that's not necessarily possible (I don't completely understand all the answers to those questions).

This works as it is:

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(json){

    var data_points = [];
    for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
        data_points.push([json[i].name, json[i].age]);
    }

    $(function () {
       //do stuff with data_points
```

but I don't know how to incorporate the second JSON call to make another list for the function at the end to use.

Comment: Do you need data from the first file in order to fetch the second, or can you ask for both simultaneously and just wait until both have arrived?

Comment: I'm graphing the data on the same set of axes so I need them at the same time, but I could get either one first or simultaneously.  Just can't build the graph until I have them both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery deferred loading.

```
var xFile, yFile;

var requestX = $.getJSON("data1.json", function(json){
    xFile = json;
});

var requestY = $.getJSON("data2.json", function(json){
    yFile = json;
});

$.when(requestX, requestY).then(function(){
   // do something;
   // this function only gets called when both requestX & requestY complete.
});
```

Check out [JQuery WHEN](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Comment: I think I prefer `$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) )
  .then( myFunc, myFailure );`

Comment: @mplungjan where would you hold your response in that case ?

Comment: @mplungjan just read its documentation, we get both responses in success callback. Would be much cleaner that way.

Comment: Especially since I believe your construct is not deferring the calls

Comment: @mplungjan agree. Ajax calls starts before handing it over to differed API in my case.

Answer (score 0):

An ajax request is ONE request for ONE resource. You can't fetch two different resources with the same request. You'd either need TWO requests:

```
var completed = 0;

$.getJSON('file1.json', function(json) {
    completed++;
    if (completed == 2) { all_done(); }
}
$.getJSON('file2.json', function(json) {
    completed++;
    if (completed == 2) { all_done(); }
}

function all_done(...) { ... }
```

Or simply combine your two json files into a single one on the server:

```
{"file1":{data from file one here}, "file2":{data from file two here}}
```

and access them as `data.file1` and `data.file2` in your code.

Comment: @mplungjan: still two calls. This has the virtual of doing the calls in parallel, rather than enforcing sequential calling.

Comment: They're honestly not huge files, and this is for a one-off task.  I thought about nesting them, but that seemed really ugly.  I like this solution; I'm testing it now.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set a var to indicate the file is loaded and call the same function while checking the status. This might be a bad idea depending on the amount of data in the JSON.

```
var xFileLoaded = false, yFileLoaded = false;
var xFile, yFile;

$.getJSON("data.json", function(json){
    xFile = json;
    xFileLoaded = true;
    doSomething();
});

$.getJSON("data.json", function(json){
    yFile = json;
    yFileLoaded = true;
    doSomething();
});

function doSomething() {
    if(xFileLoaded && yFileLoaded) {
        // good to go
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using something very similar to @MarcB's solution, I would keep the files in an array and generalize things slightly:

```
var files = ["file1.json", "file2.json"];
var results = {};
var completed = 0;

function afterEach(fileName, json) {
    results[fileName] = json;
    if (++completed >= files.length) {
        afterAll();
    }
}

files.forEach(function (file) {
    $.getJSON(file, afterEach.bind(this, file));
});
```

This should request all files in parallel, allowing the browser to choose how many connections to actually open and download. After each finishes, the results (`json`) are put in a hash for storage, under the filename. After all files have completed (assuming `files` doesn't change), then `afterAll` function will be called.

Answer (score 0):

It exists with jquery an elegant way to do this :

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({
        url: 'file1.json/',
        success: function(data) {
            // Treatement
        }
    }),
    $.ajax({
        url: 'file2.json',
        success: function(data) {
            // Treatement
        }
    })
).then( function(){
    // Two calls are completed
});
```

Once the two calls are completed, you can do any manipulation in the block "then".